# Array reduction while duplicates are present

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

I have an array of numbers:

```
[2,1,5,10,10,1]
```

a) Find elements that are repeated at least 2 times

Here we have index 3 and 4 with values 10 (if more than 2 occurrences are there then we need to select the positions that occur first)

b) remove the first item, that is remove 10 at index 3.

Next, divide the next item by 2 and update the array. so the item at index 4 with value 10 becomes 10/2 = 5

So array becomes `[2,1,5,5,1]`

c) Repeat the above steps. Break the steps if the repeated item has the value 0 or if there is no repeated element in the array.

So in the next step array becomes:
[2,1,2,1] -> Because we have 5,5, remove 1st 5, and update the second 5 by dividing by 2 and taking the floor value
[1,1,1] -> because we have 2,2 in the above step
[0,1] -> because we have 1,1 in the above step

Finally, the answer is [0,1]

constraints:
size of the array is 1 to 10^5
items in the array are 1 to 10^9

Here is my code:-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(solve(Arrays.asList(2,1,5,10,10,1)));//[0,1]
    }


public static List<Integer> solve(List<Integer> arr) {
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>(arr);
    while(true) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        Map<Integer, List<Integer>> m1 = new HashMap<>();

        int repeated = 0, idx1 = -1, idx2 = -1;
        for(int i=0; i<result.size(); i++) {
            int e = result.get(i);
            int count = map.getOrDefault(e, 0)+1;
            map.put(e, count);
            List<Integer> list = m1.getOrDefault(e, new ArrayList<>());
            list.add(i);
            m1.put(e, list);
            if(count >1 ) {
                if(e > repeated) {
                    repeated = e;
                    List<Integer> inn = m1.get(e);
                    idx1 = inn.get(0);
                    idx2 = inn.get(1);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if(repeated == 0) {
            break;
        }
        result.set(idx2, repeated/2);
        result.remove(idx1);
    }   
    return result;
}
```

This code fails with time-out errors whenever the input array size is 10^5. AS the time complexity of my code is O(n^2), how to solve this in less time complexity

Comment: Note that if you wrote working code (that you came up with, not just copy-pasted), and you want help improving performance, this is [not the right place to ask](/help/on-topic). Instead, that's what the [codereview.se] site is for (but remember to, of course, read _their_ rules on what's on topic and how to ask for help before posting too)

Comment: As long as they follow the code review rules, and explain what they already tried to improve performance, it's a perfectly fine code review question. Naturally, if it's phrased as "do my work for me" then that's off topic on any stackexchange site.

Comment: Is this online for testing somewhere?

Comment: @KellyBundy, Its not available

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Where does that page say that this is not the right place?

Comment: @KellyBundy, @ k314159,  I have updated the title and index positions now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O(n) solution: Proceed just once from left to right. Remember the index of each value. If you come across a duplicate, immediately "delete" it at the first index (actually just mark it for deletion at the end) and halve the current value. The halving might make it a duplicate of another value, so do this in a while-loop.

Python code since I don't like Java:

```py
def solve(arr):
    index = {}
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        while arr[i] in index:
            if arr[i] == 0:
                return [a for a in arr if a is not None]
            arr[index.pop(arr[i])] = None
            arr[i] //= 2
        index[arr[i]] = i
    return [a for a in arr if a is not None]

print(solve([2,1,5,10,10,1]))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jVJLTsMwEJVY5hSzTKTQBlaokq_Ail0UVSaZUKuOHTkOLUKchE03cCiWnAR_k5SyYDd-783ved4_-xe9k-J0-hh1e333dfXNul4qDYqKRnZJ0mALg-TPuB24PKRUqWyTABx2jCM8qBHtC4CJBo9A4PXNPVupgOVADQ4oxg4V1Tglu4TWsy4xgg4WUgOdEQCFelQCTPYEmrhkFazXBG4nsEHuCVuypFU1MY8K6T42DqwZljkI-YCx3aLVvPli7r_WtFsYt54w5SicNpun9z6FcS_XjU54nhAozrnFTCV17ZxpRh8MHJxd91JgdZY4-bDqZZ_6-pnd2Uovlb-tDCY5anbq35Mklt_OxtwUzhIrJuGyVvVOshqHNCqKIsthT1xgtHjssdZGfn585aayrMJh5BO7IHrFhE4jTUKZHOzX-DjL_KmHi4-X_wM) with testing.

Comment: @user85421 [Yes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=lVC9CsIwEMa1T3FjC2rVSYS-gotjyBBoYgPlUtLUH8QncemiD-XTmFxaRZy8TLnv7_huj-bsKoN9f--cmq2fk10pFbSmPshUWJttEvCjsZQnKOBypa8yFrRfghW4l2ktkbgDOcyx0rUEv2SaByIZfGDyVCNeFLD4xsJY6TqLwATFieDi-SQD3QIaB1uDkn8JyTFkzRvTpNE_8wlE_WVyyPMCVm-ApCxCQaWTvy5JGqvRpbE9tpzS41kWux0qHqt-AQ), returns `[0,0]`.

Comment: @user85421 Before. See the OP's code.

Comment: Just curious to know `I don't like Java`, is Java going to be outdated in the future?

Comment: @technotigr I have no idea. I just don't like it because I'd need to type a lot more code to get things done. And from the past I vaguely remember that some things were incredibly frustrating to do in Java.